# Tailwind style not fully applied in dangerouslySetInnerHtml content

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, qwik

I have a HTML file with Tailwind styles that is saved in my database, so it should be fetched first which will have the result in a HTML string. It will be placed in `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, the code is like this (I'm using Qwik)

```
export const useHTML = routeLoader$(async (path) => {
    // const domainName = path.url.host
    let domainName = path.url.host
    let htmlFile = ''

    if (path.url.host === 'localhost:5173') {
        domainName = 'page.id'
    }

    if (path.pathname) {
        htmlFile = `linkToMyFile/index.html`
    } else {
        htmlFile = `linkToMyFile/index.html`
    }

    const responseHtml = await fetch(htmlFile);

    return (await responseHtml.text() as string)
});

export default component$(() => {

    const htmlContent = useHTML().value;

    const htmlString: string = htmlContent.toString();

    return (
        <>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={htmlContent} />
        </>
    )
})
```

I also made a custom config for styling. I modify the `tailwind.config.js` to match the style from the fetched html code. the Tailwind config code looks like this

```
export default {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'],
  theme: {
    screens: {
        xs: '480px',
        sm: '640px',
        md: '768px',
        lg: '1024px',
        xl: '1280px',
        '2xl': '1400px',
    },
    colors: {
        current: 'currentColor',
        transparent: 'transparent',

        black: '#000',
        white: '#fff',

        //the rest of the code
    },
    fontWeight: {
        hairline: '100',
        thin: '200',
        light: '300',
        normal: '400',
        medium: '500',
        semibold: '600',
        bold: '700',
        extrabold: '800',
        black: '900',
    },
    fontFamily: {
        body: '"Clash Display"',
        heading: '"Clash Display"',
        sans: 'ui-sans-serif',
        serif: 'ui-serif, Georgia',
    },

//the rest of the default style code
```

The result is not like what I expected it to be. It seems the issue is probably in my fetched html code that I placed in `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. The Tailwind config is applied before the fetching process done. I tried to write the code directly inside the prop, it works fine. but it should be dynamic so the fetching process is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML files are on the same file system as where Tailwind compiles, consider adding `content` file globs to cover these files. Otherwise, you may need to look at [configuring `safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) to tell Tailwind to compile CSS rules for classes it never sees.

Comment: oh it works! i add some of the custom style to the safelist. Thanks!